# Why adding facebook pixel code reduces the score on gtmetrix?

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance, plugin, gtmetrix

My score website on gtmetrix is A. When I add facebook pixel code, the scrore is B

Look at this :

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

I want to add the Facebook pixel code on my website, but I don't want it to reduce the score

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> Why adding facebook pixel code reduces the score on gtmetrix?

The reason the Facebook pixel reduces your GTMetrix score is because it is an additional script with a short caching time, and GTMetrix's algorithms give better scores when you have fewer scripts and they have longer caching times.

> How can I solve this problem?

Having a "B" score with GTMetrix is not a problem, since GTMetrix is an artificial measurement that only loosely correlates with actual page speed in practice.

> I want to add the Facebook pixel code on my website, but I don't want it to reduce the score

The solution to this is to prevent it from blocking page rendering by including it before the end of your `body` tag instead of in the `head` tag. This has tradeoffs, however, as it's [more likely to be blocked or to not get the chance to finish loading before the user navigates away from the page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/).

I would *not* recommend doing this, as it may negatively impact your site. I think it makes much more sense to just be okay with the "B" rating on GTMetrix.

Comment: Great answer.  I read some references that say that Facebook pixel code can be placed in Google Analytics. Maybe this is a good solution because I don't need to placed the facebook pixel script on the head tag. But I just put it on google analytics. Seems that this will not reduce the score on gtmetrix

Comment: @SuccessMan I haven't ever heard of Facebook Pixel being able to be placed in Google Analytics. Maybe there's something I don't know about this, or maybe you are confusing it with Google Tag Manager.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean Facebook Pixel placed in Google Tag Manager.

Comment: I want to ask. I have added the Google Analytics script to my website. If I want to use Google Tag Manager, do I need to add the Google Tag Manager script again to my website? or not necessary because I already use google analytics?

Comment: I'm not sure, but Tag Manager is just a way to manage tags. It won't make the page load any faster than just including your scripts manually, it's just a tool to help organize them and include them automatically.

Comment: Okay. I want to be sure of one thing. I have google analytics script in my website. Do I need to add the Google Tag Manager script again to my website?

Comment: Not sure. That would be a perfect candidate for a new post here if the answer isn't easy to Google. I'm sure someone else would know!

Comment: I had make a new question

Comment: Look at this :  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129573/do-i-need-to-add-the-google-tag-manager-if-i-already-have-google-analytics

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the loading time of your site with and without Facebook pixel? Isnt't that  the problem? If you check this WP Rocket article, it also mentions that such tracking methods can have effect on site speed, thus cause worst grade on metric sites: https://wp-rocket.me/blog/how-third-party-tags-and-trackers-impact-website-performance/

If we are talking about SEO effects, adding a SEO pixel has advantages as well. For example, the Moz Spam Score is calculated by using 27 factors, and one of them is this:

**19. Facebook Pixel The Facebook tracking pixel is almost never present on spam sites.**

https://moz.com/help/link-explorer/link-building/spam-score

So, I don't see any problem to use the Facebook pixel, if it doesn't slow down your site. But I belive it does not.